# Как реализовать переход бота между голосовыми каналами с отправкой сообщений?

Tags: discord, бот

Я хочу написать бота, который в рандомное время присылает сообщение и в нем отмечает пользователя, так вот можно ли сделать так, чтоб он отмечал тех людей, который сидят в любом голосовом канале сервера.
А это мой код на данный момент:

```
@bot.command()
async def random(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    users = ctx.guild.members
    user1 = choice(users)
    await ctx.send(f" {user1}")
```

Как я думаю, нужно сделать через tasks.loop, но еще не понимаю как.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил, вот код.

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале.")
        return

    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f"Я присоединился к голосовому каналу: {voice_channel.name}")
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        await ctx.send(f"{bot.user.name} полетел в : {voice_channel.name}")

@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client is None:
        await ctx.send("Я не нахожусь в голосовом канале.")
        return
    await voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("Я покинул голосовой канал.")

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if member == bot.user and before.channel != after.channel:
        await bot.get_channel(after.channel.id).send(f"Я сменил голосовой канал на {after.channel.name}")
```